# I want the protagonist to win, but the antagonist is overpowered

Tags: fiction, narrative

I am writing a story about a normal teenager who is suddenly transported to this world that will soon be attacked by a powerful enemy overlord that rarely shows himself.  I would like the protagonist to win, but since the overlord is so strong I am unsure where to begin.  It is supposed to end off on a good note, but now I am debating to kill off the protag at the end of the story, which I do not want to do.  Do I need to re-write the story to change the outcome?

Comment: Hi Lavender09362. Welcome to Writing.SE. Why don't you check out the [tour](https://writing.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help centre](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help) to find out what types of questions to ask, so you're writing can improve like mine has, through this site. And don't worry about the closure - my first question was closed and I am nearly 1K rep on the site now.